# Not in clause two list<> objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a query like this :

```
select * from Subjects
where subjectid not in ( select subjectid from results)
```

for that I have an object querying results table

```
 var _results = 
     new List<C_MiscObjects.obj_Results>();
 _results = _Enrollment.GetResultView(Convert.ToInt16(lblSid.Text), lblCourseid.Text);
```

second object is as under

```
List<CoursesDetail> _CD = _Enrollment.GetSubjects(lblCourseid.Text);
```

Now want to filter records of _CD which are in _results. i.e.

```
! _CD.subjectid.contains( _results.subjectid)
```

Comment: http://www.codeducky.org/sql-queries-in-linq/#where-in may be helpful.

Comment: you may try `_CD = _Enrollment.GetSubjects(lblCourseid.Text).Where(s => !_results.Any(r => r.subjectid == s.subjectid))`

Answer (score 0):

**SQL:**

```
select * from Subjects
where subjectid not in ( select subjectid from results)
```

**LINQ:**

```
var query= Subjects.Where(s=>
                   !results.Select(r=>r.subjectid).Contains(s.subjectid));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this :

```
 _CD.Where(c => !_results.Select(r => r.subjectid).Contains(c.subjectid))
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query itself can be rewritten in terms of a left join between the 2 tables as:

```
select * from subjects s
left join results r on s.subjectid = r.subjectid
where r.subjectid is null
```

Translated to LINQ, this becomes:

```
var filtered = _CD
            .GroupJoin(_results, x => x.subjectid, y => y.subjectid, (x,y) => new {x,y})
            .SelectMany(xy => xy.y.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x,y) => new {x,y})
            .Where(xy => xy.y == null)
            .Select(xy => xy.x);
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HHHCOS35954)